# Docusign Unable to Update Form Fields or Custom Fields in Template Document

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to update the fields in the template attached documents. I have tried to use the below code to update the custom fields , but not able to see any changes on the document sent to the user.Is it possible to change the custom fields in the template programmatically ?

```
 TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole
            {
                Email = "senderemailid@gmail.com",
                Name = "ABHAY DHAR",
                RoleName = "Test1"
            };

            tRole.Tabs = new Tabs();
            tRole.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
            Text textTab = new Text();
            textTab.TabLabel = "Dummy_Custom";
            textTab.Value = "RedPlanetNote2";
            tRole.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(textTab);


            List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRole };

            // add the role to the envelope and assign valid templateId from your account
            envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;
            envDef.TemplateId = "964300cb-9ccf-471f-8d9d-5ad894e8d99f";
           // envDef.CustomFields = docCustomFields;
            // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
            envDef.Status = "sent";

            // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

Comment: did you get it solved?

Comment: Sorry , I was not able to solve , at that time, the SDK did not support updating the custom fields. The answer below confirms that .

Answer (score 1):

I battled a lot with the API in java, but finally with the help of C# code from github link: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/75 , I made it work.

Now my templates on docusign are getting automatically populated using following code.

Just one further info. I went into Docusign web application and created a template there. Then I placed a document in this template, where I placed custom fields like in this screenshot:

[image]

Working Code:

` EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.setEmailSubject("KYC XXX");
envDef.setTemplateId("xxxxxx-76cb-4226-adb4-3180358c8dec");

List<TemplateRole> templateRolesList = new ArrayList<TemplateRole>();
TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();

Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new ArrayList<TemplateRole>();
List<Text> textTabs = new ArrayList<>();
tRole.setRoleName("Signer");

Text textTab1 = new Text();
textTab1.setTabLabel("userinfo");
textTab1.setValue("RedPlanetNote2");

Text textTab3 = new Text();
textTab3.setTabLabel("business_activity");
textTab3.setValue("We sell cars");

textTabs.add(textTab1);
textTabs.add(textTab3);

tabs.setTextTabs(textTabs);
tRole.setTabs(tabs);
tRole.setName("xxx");
tRole.setEmail("xxx@gmail.com");

templateRolesList.add(tRole);

envDef.setTemplateRoles(templateRolesList);
envDef.setStatus("sent");

try {
    return envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
} catch (ApiException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    LOGGER.error(String.format("Exception occurred while sending signed KYC Template with prepopulation email %s with ", e));
}`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Company and Job Title fields (tabs), plus name and email fields are special. They reflect properties of the recipient (whether a signer or not).

See this answer: https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00082402

I don't know if you can set them programmatically. I will ask another team to also look at your question. You can test by first trying to set the fields in a simple envelope definition (no template involved). If you can, then the issue becomes one of setting a field value via a template.

Note that these fields are handled differently if the signer has their own DocuSign account or not.